# What happened at the Central Park turtle pond in F. Paul Wilson's The Touch?

Tags: f-paul-wilson

I'm reading the Adversary Cycle by F. Paul Wilson and just finished book three, *The Touch*. Everything makes sense to me except one line from the beginning of chapter 42:

> As Alan hung up, he glanced down at the morning headlines screaming
> about some bizarre occurrence near the Central Park turtle pond
> yesterday. Was that what had so disturbed him?

This is both deliberately vague ("bizarre occurrence") and specific ("Central Park turtle pond yesterday"). I feel like I'm supposed to know what it's talking about. I thought maybe it would come up later in the book, but no. In fact that line is the only occurrence of "central park" and "turtle pond" in the book.

Dropping a weird non-sequitur and not revisiting it does not seem to be in keeping with Wilson's style, from what I've seen so far. But maybe that's all this is?

Is the bizarre occurrence near the Central Park turtle pond explained anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fifteen books later I finally know what happened!

The "bizarre occurrence" at the turtle pond refers to the climax of F. Paul Wilson's *Ground Zero*, in which

> the *Fhinntmanchca* tackles the Lady and her dog and all three are instantly annihilated.

The dates match up: *Ground Zero* is immediately before *The Touch* in the "Secret History of the World" chronology, so they definitely occur in the same year. The incident in *Ground Zero* happens on a Sunday in July, and the newspaper article in *The Touch* is on Monday July 13th.

The only oddity is that *The Touch* was written in 1986 while *Ground Zero* was in 2009. But the copy of *The Touch* that I read was part of a re-release of the Adversary Cycle books published in 2018, so maybe the line about the turtle pond was added in for that edition.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to relate to an earlier passage in *The Tomb*

> **Kolabati hurried toward Central Park West.** This was a residential
> district with trees near the curb and cars lining both sides of the
> street. Nice in the daytime, but at night there were too many deep
> shadows, too many dark hiding places. It was not rakoshi she
> feared—not while she wore her necklace. It was humans. And with good
> reason: Look what had happened Wednesday night because a hoodlum
> thought an iron and topaz necklace looked valuable.
>
> She relaxed when she reached Central Park West. There was plenty of
> traffic there despite the lateness of the hour, and the sodium lamps
> high over the street made the very air around her seem to glow. Empty
> cabs cruised by. She let them pass. There was something she had to do
> before she flagged one down.
>
> Kolabati walked along the curb until she found a sewer grate. **She
> reached into her purse and removed the bottle of rakoshi elixir.** She
> hadn’t liked stealing it from Jack, for she would have to fabricate a
> convincing explanation later. But it was his safety that counted, and
> to assure that, she would steal from him again and again.
>
> **She unscrewed the cap and poured the green mixture down the sewer,
> waiting until the last drop fell.**

Presumably the grate led to the turtle pond and the turtles behaved unusually.

Comment: Interesting possibility! But I don't think the timelines match up:
The pouring out of the Rakoshi serum happens on Saturday August 4th (from the dates on the chapter headings), while the newspaper headline happens around July 13th (from the tide chart Charles Axford consults).

Also, F. Paul Wilson's ["Secret History of the World" timeline](https://repairmanjack.com/books/the-secret-history-of-the-world/) puts The Tomb in year zero-minus-three and The Touch in year zero-minus-one, so two full years apart.

Comment: @Robert - It's the only solid mention of Central Park and water that I could find.

Comment: @Robert  maybe it takes two years for the "toddler mutant ninja turtles" to get big enough to attack people or start talking to people or do something else bizzare.

Comment: Was there a real-world occurence we are supposed to know about?